# Ubuntu will not boot on Chromebook C720

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, chromebook

I've recently installed Linux on my Chromebook, and it’s turning out to be a complete nightmare. It’s a Chromebook C720.

My first problem is that Ubuntu will not boot. Whenever I enter the user name and password, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib
/update=notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck
-at reboot: Read-only file system.
```

Furthermore, something is wrong with my administrator profile. Every intervention I attempt in order to fix this problem is futile, as it seems my administrator privileges are non-existent. Whenever I use the `sudo` command in conjunction with some other request, I receive this error:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/user/tty1: No such file or directory.
```

Another example of this administrator issue is my being denied access to certain files. For example, when I type `/etc/fstab`, I get this lovely response:

```
-bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied
```

As you can see, it's one problem after another with this device. Before I consider reinstallation, I wanted to try and fix it at least. Can anyone provide me with a straightforward method of handling these issues?

Finally, I am aware that I can use the “edit” function on bootloader and change `ro` to `rw` on the Linux line. (I can also boot up in start up.) I would rather not have to use these roundabout techniques to boot up my laptop, though.

Answer (score 0):

Once you can boot in after changing to rw in GRUB, just edit the default GRUB config file to make it always rw.

You may also be able to do this instead (although it may not fix the problem, it won't hurt anything)

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```